# Finding Capacity in the Current Cycle with Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an app that tracks capacity per cycle (where a cycles are months from activation). For example:

- Jan 29, 2015 12:00PM - Feb 28, 2015 12:00PM (cycle #1)
- Feb 28, 2015 12:00PM - Mar 29, 2015 12:00PM (cycle #2)
- Mar 29, 2015 12:00PM - Apr 29, 2015 12:00PM (cycle #3)
- ...

The piece of information being tracked is the 'activated' date (i.e. the start of the initial cycle). Is there a good way to calculate the cycle (range) for a given date? My current implementation works but seems wasteful (having to loop up to the date):

```
def period(activated, time)
  cycles = 0
  cycles = cycles.next while activated + cycles.next.months < time
  return (activated + cycles.months)..(activated + cycles.next.months)
end
```

Comment: Is `activated` a `datetime` param and `time` is `time`? Or both are `datetime`? As an example, are you trying to now how many cycles from `Jan 29, 2015 12:00PM` to `Apr 29, 2015 12:00PM`?

Comment: `activated` and `time` are both time objects. `activated` is the start of the initial cycle. `time` is the time I'm trying to find a cycle for. The result of the function is a range of times (i.e. Feb 28 .. Mar 29).

Answer (score 0):

To Rails, [`1.month` is `30.days`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5144d8a5529baebdaf76dbf253d1d6f2d8689b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb#L20-L22), so indeed, with a little math you can do this without all the iteration:

```
def period(activated, time)
  days = (time - activated).to_i
  cycle_idx = days / 30
  cycle_start = activated + cycle_idx * 30
  cycle_start..(cycle_start + 30)
end
```

Let me break it down:

```
activated = DateTime.parse('Jan 29, 2015 12:00PM') # => #<DateTime: 2015-01-29T12:00:00+00:00 ...>
time = DateTime.parse('Apr 15, 2015 6:00PM')       # => #<DateTime: 2015-04-30T12:00:00+00:00 ...>

# Get the number of days between `activated` and `time`.
days = (time - activated).to_i # => (305/4).to_i => 76

# Divide by 30 to get the cycle number (0-based).
cycle_idx = days / 30 # => 2

# Multiply the cycle number by 30 and add it to `activated` to get
# the beginning of the cycle.
cycle_start = activated + cycle_idx * 30 # => #<DateTime: 2015-03-30T12:00:00+00:00 ...>

# Add 30 more to get the end of the cycle.
cycle_start..(cycle_start + 30)
# => #<DateTime: 2015-03-30T12:00:00+00:00 ...>
#    ..#<DateTime: 2015-04-29T12:00:00+00:00 ...>
```

You'll notice, as I did, that the 3rd cycle begins on Mar. 30, not Mar. 29, unlike in your example. As far as I can tell, this is the same result you'd get with your code, since Mar. 30, 2015 is 30 days after Feb. 28, 2015.

Comment: `1.month` is **not** `30.days` in Rails. For example, try from your rails console: 

- `Time.parse("January 31, 2015") + 1.month # February 28th`
- `Time.parse("January 31, 2015") + 2.months # March 31th`
- `Time.parse("January 31, 2015") + 3.months # April 30th`

`1.month` is in fact an `ActiveSupport::Duration` that has some fancy functions built in for handling addition to times / dates.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. I saw `self * 30.days` in [`Integer#months`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/ef5144d8a5529baebdaf76dbf253d1d6f2d8689b/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/integer/time.rb#L20-L22) and made a leap. Do you know of another solution that would serve OP's use case?

Answer (score 0):

```
def period(activated, time)
  cycle = 1.month
  # diff is how many cycles between activated and time
  diff = ((time - activated)/1.month.second).floor
  (activated + diff.months)..(activated + (diff.month + cycle))
end
```